# Response.Redirect to a Div

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this code to redirect to a new aspx page.

```
protected void OrdersGrid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            string orderId= DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "orderId").ToString();
            string Location = "test.aspx" + "?OrderID=" + orderId;
            Response.Redirect(Location);
            e.Row.Attributes["onClick"] = string.Format("javascript:window.location='{0}';", Location);
            e.Row.Style["cursor"] = "pointer";
            test.Attributes["style"] = "visibility:visible;display:block;";
        }
    }
```

the code works fine
I wonder if I can replace my page (test.aspx) in `Response.Redirect` with a div #id
I need orderId to be used in the second div to display Order_Details within the same page.
I know I can use other methods to retreive orderId, but i used the above code to make the whole row in GridView as a link

thank you!

Comment: No, you cannot "redirect" to a div.  The concept is nonsense.  What are you actually trying to do?   Are you trying to update a div with data coming from the server?

Comment: @KirkWoll thanks for your answer. i want to retrieve orderId from gridview and use it in the second div.
i can do this using 'Response.Redirect' to another page, but not a div

Comment: That's because you can't redirect to a div. Redirecting is for changing URL's. You're going to be on the same URL. Try just updating the markup for the div instead of redirecting. By the way, any code after a call to Response.Redirect() will not run.